# How to loop over an array from the vuex store

Tags: javascript, arrays, vuex, vuejs3

I'm using vuex and vuejs 3 and I'm trying to loop over an array from the vuex store butt it keeps throwing an error saying the array is undefined.
I tried loging the data and it is working but when using it with the v-for directive it says it's undefined
here's the store

```
import { createStore } from 'vuex'

export default createStore({
  state: {
    AddTaskShown: false,
    Tasks: []
  },
  getters: {
  },
  mutations: {
      ToggleAddTask(state) {
      state.AddTaskShown = !state.AddTaskShown;
    },
    addTask(st, {name, description, date }) {
      st.Tasks = [...st.Tasks, {name, description, date}]
    },
  },
  actions: {
  },
  modules: {
  }
})
```

and here's the component

```
<template>
  <div class="grid grid-cols-1 gap-1 py-3">
    <Task :v-for="Task in $store.state.Tasks" :Task="Task" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Task from "@/components/Task.vue";

export default {
  components: {
    Task,
  },
};
</script>
```

and the child component ( the one I'm looping)

````
<template>
<div class="mx-5 my-1 bg-slate-700 p-4 text-white rounded-lg">
    <input type="checkbox" class="w-4 h-4 mr-2"> {{ Task.name }}
</div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: "Task",
  props: {
    Task: Object,
  },
};
</script>```
and it gives me an error saying
```Task.vue?c155:2 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')
    at Proxy.render (Task.vue?c155:2:1)
    at renderComponentRoot (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?d2dd:896:1)
    at ReactiveEffect.componentUpdateFn [as fn] (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?d2dd:5580:1)
    at ReactiveEffect.run (reactivity.esm-bundler.js?89dc:185:1)
    at instance.update (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?d2dd:5694:1)
    at setupRenderEffect (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?d2dd:5708:1)
    at mountComponent (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?d2dd:5490:1)
    at processComponent (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?d2dd:5448:1)
    at patch (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?d2dd:5038:1)
    at mountChildren (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?d2dd:5234:1)```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use set the `Tasks state` in a `computed` property to watch the changes happen to the `state`, it gives error, because the template executes before the `Tasks` state initialize.

Also, there is another issue which is a naming conflict between the component name `Task` and the single array item `Task`.

You need to update the props name to `task` instead of `Task`

It would be better to always name your variables as `camelCase`

```
<template>
<div class="grid grid-cols-1 gap-1 py-3">
    <Task :v-for="task in Tasks" :task="task" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Task from "@/components/Task.vue";

export default {
  components: {
    Task,
  },
  computed: {
     Tasks() {
         return this.$store.state.Tasks
     }
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: Still giving the same error.

Comment: Do you try to `console.log` the `this.$store.state.Tasks` inside the `computed` property?

Comment: Yes I did, and it output the array and it was working  but not in the template

Comment: I think also there is a naming conflict issue, I update the answer please check again.

Comment: nope, still not working

Comment: There are a lot of errors in your code, try to re-produce the error in any live editor like codesandbox, so we can debug and help you.

Comment: the fix acutally happened to be to switch from computed to a lifecycle hook like mounted or created